# Creating windows in Chrome App ignores bounds when launching?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app, pixi.js

I use the `background.js` script to create new windows, but when I set the bounds when using the `chrome.app.window.create` method and pass it parameters for the `CreateWindowOptions` object the are used the first time, but ignored whenever I relaunch the app.

On OSX, it seems that calling the methods `setPosition` and `setSize` after the create callback on the window's outerBounds object the app will then respond to the bounds I try to set.  However, this doesn't appear to work on Windows 10 at all.

It seems somehow the windows I create persist when the app is closed.  I'm not sure how to clear them, especially if the user closes the app uses the menu or OS to quit.  Is there some way to make sure to destroy or clear these windows, or force the Chrome App to set the bounds I set without reverting to some previous state?

The windows I create are running PixiJS if that makes any difference.  I do call a destroy method on the windows when the close event is triggered, but that has no affect.

Here's my background script:

```
(function( global ) {

    "use strict";


    /* ----- VARS ----- */
    var displayInfo;
    var isMultiDisplay;

    var controlDisplayIndex;
    var controlBounds;
    var controlLoaded;
    var controlWindow;

    var gameDisplayIndex;
    var gameBounds;
    var gameLoaded;
    var gameWindow;


    /* ----- CONSTANTS ----- */
    var CONTROL_WIDTH = 1920;
    var CONTROL_HEIGHT = 1080;

    var GAME_WIDTH = 2160;
    var GAME_HEIGHT = 3840;

    var FRAME_OPTIONS = {
        type: "none"
    };


    /* ----- FUNCTIONS ----- */
    function init() {
        console.log( "background.js: init" );
        console.info( "background.js: ", chrome.app.window.getAll() );

        isMultiDisplay = false;

        controlLoaded = false;
        gameLoaded = false;

        loadDisplayInfo();

    };

    function loadDisplayInfo() {
        console.log( "background.js: loadDisplayInfo" );

        chrome.system.display.getInfo( onDisplayInfo );

    };

    function createWindows() {
        console.log( "background.js: createWindows" );

        isMultiDisplay = ( displayInfo.length > 0 );

        if ( isMultiDisplay ) {

            var i = 0;
            var length = 2;

            for ( i; i < length; i++ ) {

                if ( displayInfo[i].isPrimary )
                    controlDisplayIndex = i;
                else 
                    gameDisplayIndex = i;

            }

            gameBounds = {
                height: displayInfo[ gameDisplayIndex ].workArea.height,
                left: displayInfo[ gameDisplayIndex ].workArea.left,
                top: displayInfo[ gameDisplayIndex ].workArea.top,
                width: displayInfo[ gameDisplayIndex ].workArea.width
            };

            controlBounds = {
                height: displayInfo[ controlDisplayIndex ].workArea.height,
                left: displayInfo[ controlDisplayIndex ].workArea.left,
                top: displayInfo[ controlDisplayIndex ].workArea.top,
                width: displayInfo[ controlDisplayIndex ].workArea.width
            };

        } else {

            // This assumes single monitor is in landscape.
            gameBounds = {
                top: displayInfo[0].workArea.top,
                left: displayInfo[0].workArea.left,
                height: displayInfo[0].workArea.height,
                width: Math.floor( displayInfo[0].workArea.height * GAME_WIDTH / GAME_HEIGHT )
            };

            controlBounds = {
                top: displayInfo[0].workArea.top,
                left: displayInfo[0].workArea.left + gameBounds.width,
                width: gameBounds.width,
                height: Math.floor( gameBounds.width * CONTROL_HEIGHT / CONTROL_WIDTH )
            };

        }

        console.info( "Game Bounds:", gameDisplayIndex, gameBounds.left, gameBounds.top, gameBounds.width, gameBounds.height );
        console.info( "Control Bounds:", controlDisplayIndex, controlBounds.left, controlBounds.top, controlBounds.width, controlBounds.height );

        var state = ( isMultiDisplay ) ? "fullscreen" : "normal";

        // Game
        chrome.app.window.create( "window-game.html", {
            id: "gameWindow",
            bounds: gameBounds,
            frame: FRAME_OPTIONS,
            resizable: true,
            state: state
        }, onGameWindowCreated );

        // Control
        chrome.app.window.create( "window-control.html", {
            id: "controlWindow",
            bounds: controlBounds,
            frame: FRAME_OPTIONS,
            resizable: true,
            state: state
        }, onControlWindowCreated );

    };


    /* ----- EVENT LISTENERS ----- */
    function onLaunched() {
        console.log( "background.js: onLaunched" );

        init();

    };

    function onDisplayInfo( info ) {
        console.log( "background.js: onDisplayInfo" );

        displayInfo = info;
        createWindows();

    };

    function onControlWindowCreated( obj ) {
        console.log( "background.js: onControlWindowCreated", obj.id );

        controlLoaded = true;
        controlWindow = obj;

        controlWindow.outerBounds.setPosition( controlBounds.left, controlBounds.top );
        controlWindow.outerBounds.setSize( controlBounds.width, controlBounds.height );

        if ( isMultiDisplay ) controlWindow.fullscreen();

        //console.info( controlWindow.innerBounds.width, controlWindow.innerBounds.height );
        //console.info( controlWindow.outerBounds.width, controlWindow.outerBounds.height );

        controlWindow.onClosed.addListener( onControlWindowClosed );

    };

    function onControlWindowClosed() {
        console.log( "background.js: onControlWindowClosed" );

        controlWindow.onClosed.removeListener( onControlWindowClosed );
        controlWindow.destroy();
        controlWindow = undefined;

    };

    function onGameWindowCreated( obj ) {
        console.log( "background.js: onGameWindowCreated", obj.id );

        gameLoaded = true;
        gameWindow = obj;

        gameWindow.outerBounds.setPosition( gameBounds.left, gameBounds.top );
        gameWindow.outerBounds.setSize( gameBounds.width, gameBounds.height );

        if ( isMultiDisplay ) gameWindow.fullscreen();

        //console.info( gameWindow.innerBounds.width, gameWindow.innerBounds.height );
        //console.info( gameWindow.outerBounds.width, gameWindow.outerBounds.height );

        gameWindow.onClosed.addListener( onGameWindowClosed );

    };

    function onGameWindowClosed() {
        console.log( "background.js: onGameWindowClosed" );

        gameWindow.onClosed.removeListener( onGameWindowClosed );
        gameWindow.destroy();
        gameWindow = undefined;

    };


    /* ----- CALL ----- */
    chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener( onLaunched );

}( this ));
```

*Disclaimer: I know that Chrome Apps are being discontinued, but due to project timings I've got to finish this app off and then look to port to Electron or alternative.*

Comment: Just read that:
" If an id is also specified and a window with a matching id has been shown before, the remembered bounds will be used instead."

So, it looks like there is no way to override the bounds unless I drop the `id` property of the `CreateWindowOptions` object, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a window and set the `id` property in the `CreateWindowOptions` object, the last known bounds for that window will be saved by the Chrome Apps platform and used the next a window is created with that same id.

Here's the description from the docs on the `id` property:

> Id to identify the window. This will be used to remember the size and
>   position of the window and restore that geometry when a window with
>   the same id is later opened. If a window with a given id is created
>   while another window with the same id already exists, the currently
>   opened window will be focused instead of creating a new window.

And under the description of the `outerBounds` property:

> Used to specify the initial position, initial size and constraints of
>   the window (including window decorations such as the title bar and
>   frame). If an id is also specified and a window with a matching id has
>   been shown before, the remembered bounds will be used instead.

So, the solution is to omit the `id` property.  If you, like myself, need to do further things with that window in your script, then use the create window callback to assign a variable to that's function return parameter.

For example:

```
var myWindow;

chrome.app.window.create( "window.html", options, function( obj ) {

    myWindow = obj;

    // Do Stuff with myWindow

} );
```

I guess even attempting to set the size and position of the window after the callback isn't full-proof as is evident when I tried to do some under Windows 10.

The only remaining unknown to me is where is Google Chrome Apps storing all this window data when you give windows an id?  And is there a way to clear that (other than uninstalling the app)?

Comment: _"And is there a way to clear that"_ Not programmatically, unfortunately.